# Properties of state not setting ["This field is required."]

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, amazon-s3, react-bootstrap

I have a django/react (s3 bucket for image upload)project which adds recipes to a postgres database. In my RecipeFormContainer Component one of my properties to the recipe is an Array of ingredients. The array is supposed to be filled with objects that are made up of the key value pairs of units, quantity etc. I have written a method called addIngredients, but it does not seem to be adding the objects into my ingredients array. I get the error "ingredients: ["This field is required."]" when trying to submit my recipe and do a post. Please enlighten me with what I am missing. 
Code is as follows:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Form} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';


class RecipeFormContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title: '',
            creator: '',
            mealTime: "",
            prepTime: "",
            cookTime: "",
            image_preview: "",
            servings: "",
            directions: '',
            ingredients: [{
                units: '',
                amounts: '',
                multiples: '',
                quantity: '',
                name: ''
            }],
            image: "",

        };

        this.handleImage = this.handleImage.bind(this);
        this.handleIngredientInput = this.handleIngredientInput.bind(this);
        this.handleAddIngredients = this.handleAddIngredients.bind(this);
    }

    handleAddIngredients =(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

// the ingredients properties are not being added to the ingredients array property on state *************************

        let ingredient = {units: '',
                amounts: '',
                multiples: '',
                quantity: '',
                name: ''};

        //save the current state of ingredients array in variable ingredient
        let {ingredients} = this.state.ingredients;
        // add the ingredient object into the ingredients array ( which is a property of state)
        ingredients.push(ingredient);

        // set the new array of ingredients as the state of the property ingredients
        this.setState( {ingredients: ingredients});
    };



    handleInput = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

    };


    handleIngredientInput = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    };

    handleImage(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // this makes it show up in preview

        let file = event.target.files[0];
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = () => this.setState({image_preview:fileReader.result});
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        this.setState({image:file});
    }



    submitRecipe = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let recipe = {...this.state};
        console.log('recipe one', this.state);

        let formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("image", this.state.image);
        formData.append('title', this.state.title);
        formData.append("ingredients", this.state.ingredients);
        formData.append("mealTime", this.state.mealTime);
        formData.append("prepTime", this.state.prepTime);
        formData.append("cookTime", this.state.cookTime);
        formData.append("image_Preview", this.state.image_preview);
        formData.append("servings", this.state.servings);
        formData.append("directions", this.state.directions);
        formData.append("creator", this.state.creator);
        // formData.append("units", this.state.ingredients.units);
        // formData.append("amount", this.state.ingredients.amount);
        // formData.append("multiples", this.state.ingredients.multiples);
        // formData.append("quantity", this.state.ingredients.quantity);
        // formData.append("name", this.state.ingredients.name);

        // add line for each property of state


        const conf = {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,

        };

        fetch('/api/recipe/', conf).then((response) => {

            return response.json();

        }).then((json) => {
            this.props.addRecipe(json);

        });


    };


    render() {


        return (


            <Form onSubmit={this.submitRecipe} encType="multipart/form-data"  >

                <Form.Group onSubmit={event => {event.preventDefault(); }}  >
                    <img src={this.state.image_preview}/>
                    <input className="input" type="file"  onChange={this.handleImage} name="image" />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
                    <Form.Label>Recipe Name</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter Recipe Name Here"
                                  name="title"
                                  value={this.state.title}
                                  onChange={this.handleInput}/>


                    <Form.Label>Recipe Creator</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name Here"
                                  value={this.state.creator}
                                  name="creator"
                                  onChange={this.handleInput}/>

                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1" id="foodType">
                    <Form.Label>Example select</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control as="select">
                        <option>Breakfast</option>
                        <option>Lunch</option>
                        <option>Dinner</option>
                        <option>Dessert</option>
                        <option>Vegetarian</option>
                    </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>


                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Prep Time" className="midButt"
                              value={this.state.prepTime}
                              name="prepTime"
                              onChange={this.handleInput}/>
                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Cook Time" className="midButt"
                              value={this.state.cookTime}
                              name="cookTime"
                              onChange={this.handleInput}/>


                <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1" id="foodTemp">
                    <Form.Control as="select">
                        <option>Fahrenheit</option>
                        <option>Celsius</option>
                    </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>


                <Form.Group>
                    This Recipe Will Make: <Form.Control type="number" placeholder="servings" id="servings" value={this.state.ingredients.servings} onChange={this.handleInput} name="servings" />

                    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="cookies, loaves, etc." id="loaf" value={this.state.ingredients.multiples} onChange={this.handleIngredientInput} name="multiples"/>

                </Form.Group>

                {this.state.ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <Form.Control type="number" placeholder="#" id="numberAmount" value={this.state.ingredients.quantity} onChange={this.handleIngredientInput} name="amount"/>
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="units" id="units" value={this.state.ingredients.units} onChange={this.handleIngredientInput} name="units"/>
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Ingredient Name" id="name" value={this.state.ingredients.name} onChange={this.handleIngredientInput} name="name"/>
                        </div>
                    );
                })};

                <Button variant="light" onClick = {this.handleAddIngredients}> + </Button>
                {/*/!*will update state with event handler this.state.ingredients, append object to array *!/*/}


                <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
                    <Form.Label>Directions</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control as="textarea" rows="3"
                        value={this.state.directions}
                              name="directions"
                              onChange={this.handleInput}/>
                </Form.Group>


                <Button type="submit" variant="secondary">Save This Recipe !</Button>

            </Form>
        )
    };
}


export default RecipeFormContainer;
```

Comment: try to console.log your `this.state.ingredients` and look what's there when you add a new ingredient. Maybe the result isn't what you was expecting

Comment: It is empty. My handleIngredientInput method is not doing what I expected. I am unsure of the syntax to make the logic I want work correctly. DO you have any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your code, your `handleAddIngredients` isn't right. You commited two mistakes:

### Not collecting data from the inputs

You're not collecting the data from the state to put inside the `ingredient`. Your code creates a blank `ingredient` to put on the array.

### Trying to copy the `ingredients` array on the wrong way.

Your code "extracts" the `ingredients` from the `this.state.ingredients`, but it's not possible. Your `ingredients` belongs to your `state`, not to `state.ingredients`.

Instead of doing

```
let { ingredients } = this.state.ingredients
```

You could do

```
let { ingredients } = this.state
```

Or even

```
let ingredients = [ ...this.state.ingredients ]
```

## Conclusion

After all the fixes, your code should look like below:

```
handleAddIngredients = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();

    //Extracting the values from the state
    let { units, amounts, multiples, quantity, name } = this.state

    // Inserting the values into the new ingredient
    let ingredient = { units, amounts, multiples, quantity, name }

    // Creating the copy
    let ingredients = [ ... this.state.ingredients ]

    // add the ingredient object into the ingredients array ( which is a property of state)
    ingredients.push(ingredient);

    // set the new array of ingredients in the state
    this.setState({ingredients});
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain  that !I knew my methods were not working correctly, but was not sure how to fix them. I will try this right away !

Comment: @ChristinaRoberts, you're welcome! I recommend to you to check if all the other handles are working as expected, also.

Comment: that fixed my problem of being able to add the ingredients, but now further down, the post request is still not working. I am VERY new to the javascript and react side of things so its still a challenge to turn my logic (backend style) into valid javascript code haha

Comment: @ChristinaRoberts, as this answer solves your problem of ingredients field being empty, feel free to mark it as solution. If is there any other problem, not related with the first one, I recommend you to ask a new question